# Select and animate all divs with a class but ignore all children with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm hoping there's a simple solution to this, but I can't see it at the minute.

I'm attempting to select all divs with a class myClass, but ignore all children of said class including those that have the class myClass. For example:

```
<div class="myClass"> //select
    <div class="myClass"> //don't
      <div class="myClass"></div> //don't etc
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass">
     <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

I know this is an odd situation, it's come about from a need to slide map controls across a Google map when sliding in a side-div (so as not to cover them). The classes that need to be altered are all named 'gmnoprint' and if children are not ignored then elements within a parent are moved by double the required amount for each level of nesting.

My current solution (more of a bad hack) is to call:

```
$('div.gmnoprint').stop().animate({ 'marginLeft': '418px' }, 800);
$('div.gmnoprint').children('div.gmnoprint').stop().animate
    ({ 'marginLeft': '0px' }, 800);
```

But this is horribly inefficient and processor intensive.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I could not find anything similar.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you'll need to target parent DOM elements rather than the class itself.  assuming each first instance is a child to a common parent it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: If you have a parent container then can you maybe just use a css selector at the start to select direct children e.g. $('#container > .myClass').animate.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.gmnoprint')
    .filter( function() {
        return $(this).parent().closest('div.gmnoprint').length === 0;
    })
    .stop()
    .animate({ 'marginLeft': '418px' }, 800);
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I wasn't sure how to properly apply the filter condition to exclude children.

Answer (score 0):

These divs must all live within another container of some sort. If we assume it's id is `container`, call:

```
$('#container').children('div.gmnoprint').stop().animate({ 'marginLeft': '418px' }, 800);
```

This will only go one level deep and not select all `div.gmnoprint` elements on the page.

Comment: Unfortunately the container in question appears to be a blank div sans id/class.